# Record for an hour using mobile phone

Tags: video-capture, android, mobile

I want to record someone speaking for about an hour without any gaps. To do this i'm using a Samsung Galaxy s8.

The default video application splits the video into 4gb files when recording longer videos; which would be ok,  but when I take them into a video editor to join them,  they don't fully match up.

Is there a way round this without rooting my phone.

I've tried a few video applications and recorded to the internal and sd memories.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) is an open source app that let's you do this. You can configure it for various times including *unlimited*.

Android has typically a 4GB limit on video size. [Your one hour video will most likely exceed this limit](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110784/131553) 
. Open Camera let's you restart the video automatically after the 4 GB limit is reached which can be joined in a video editor

Comment: I don't recall the name of the video editor used

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Android version, so I don't know whether it splits into 4GB chunks, but Filmic Pro is a widely respected video camera app, and they make an Android version. The 4GB limit might be a limitation of the file system. https://www.filmicpro.com/